# How to keep only one instance of service for several components?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-di

I use **DI** to inject sevice in several components. Now it works not as one common instance.

How to keep only one instance of service for several components?

I trie to load service in `app.module` in section `providers`

Comment: Then you should have a singleton. Provide a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add a provider **only** to `@NgModule({providers: [MyService]})` (and nowhere else) then there will only be **exactly one instance** of `MyService` in your application.

This is only true when the `@NgModule()` decorator is on a non-lazy loaded module. Providers of lazy-loaded modules can be imported with [forRoot](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method) to ensure they will be singletons as well.

If you add a service to `@Component({ providers: [...]})`, then there will be as many instances as there are instances of this component.